# Make a popup div on hover appear in front of other divs?

Tags: html, css

http://www.thinkstudio.co.za/Untitled-1.html

All is in one html file, using css amd html. I have tried using z-index, it works, but the moment you hover over the pop box area, it gives problems (please see link above) Has this to do with div positioning? I need 2 divs with content inside the container area, and once you hover over it, there needs to be a popup, if there is any other easier way, please help!

Comment: Sorry I fixed the link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi there, thanks, I will use the provided guidelines next time, the link will stay up.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/53LyLmy9/

What I did was creating a JQuery event where whenever the mouse enters the popup or the box, the popup would show, and when the mouse left, it would hide.

```
$('#box,#popup').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#popup').show(); 
});
$('#box,#popup').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#popup').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is also VERY usefull! I will try another on with your solution.

Comment: No problem. This should work universally, as long you have JQuery linked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you hovering .box it loose hover at link that was trigering .box display.
Fixed your problem like this

```
   .box:hover {
     display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, just opened developer tool and add this code, everything works in chrome for me.
It's not working in your browser? I think it should

Comment: Yes, however when you move your mouse out, it doesn't hide the popup.

Comment: It does, just move it out of triggering area 

https://plnkr.co/edit/XfQ2irlkQ9xW10e2C4aj?p=preview

Comment: Thank you man! that solved my problem! I will test this in other browsers, and it works it firefox, and also safari.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Hover your mouse over, then hover it ~100px away from the right side of the box.

Comment: It's because of span(.link-spanner) width, change it and it wouldn't trigger "display:block" style.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning about position: relative and child elements with position: absolute, and By using a div with style z-index:1; and position: absolute; you can overlay your div on any other div.

z-index determines the order in which divs 'stack'. A div with a higher z-index will appear in front of a div with a lower z-index. Note that this property only works with positioned elements.

Comment: I have a link a the top, all is in one file, css also added...

http://www.thinkstudio.co.za/Untitled-1.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you hovering .box it loose hover at link that was trigering .box display. Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jyde/2sodLq6y/

```
.box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #215273;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:1;
}

.topdiv{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
}   

.container{
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
  /*Important:*/
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10;  
}

.left{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#bda97f;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;   
 }

.link-spanner{
   position:absolute; 
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}

a:hover + .box {
  display:block;   
}

.box:hover {
  display:block;
}
```